# Modify presentation of element in a TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

For this particular administration page, I'd like to turn the 'current value' (outlined in a red circle) into a link going back to the administration page for this particular object.

But I can't find where to go to make this change. I know that I need to somehow override how this 
is displayed but I can't figure it out.

What do I need to override to do what I want?

[image: current admin interface]

Admin model definition:

```
class FirmwareConfigElementsChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FirmwareConfigElements
    extra = 1

class FirmwareConfigAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    list_display = ('name', 'description')
    inlines = [FirmwareConfigElementsChoiceInline]
```

---

Using Filip's great help I've gotten to this:

```
class FirmwareConfigElementsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        klass = FirmwareConfigElementsForm
        super(klass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.type == 'incfw':
            value = self.instance.value
            url = '#'  # TODO: get the URL for the value
            hyperlink = '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, value)
            label = self.fields['type'].label.replace(value, hyperlink)
            self.fields['type'].label = label
```

But in the above code, `self.fields['type'].label` has the contents `Type` and not `Include another FW Config - BASE:IBM-HS22/HS22V` as I was expecting.

I've explored it in the debugger but I can't figure out how to get to the particular label that I want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Inline admin models have a [template property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options) you can use to supply a custom template. From there, you'll need to modify the code to add the url.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide a custom `ModelForm` for the `FirmwareConfigElements` model, which you'll set as the value for the `FirmwareConfigElementsChoiceInline.form` class attribute.

Here you'll want to override the `ModelForm.__init__()` instance method to assign a new label for the field you want to override if the form is bound:

```
class FirmwareConfigElementsForm(models.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        klass = FirmwareConfigElementsForm
        super(klass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if form.is_bound and 'value' in self.data:
            value = self.data['value']
            url = ''  # TODO: get the URL for the value
            hyperlink = '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, value)
            label = self.fields['type'].label.replace(value, hyperlink)
            self.fields['type'].label = label


class FirmwareConfigElementsChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FirmwareConfigElements
    extra = 1
    form = FirmwareConfigElementsForm
```

Now, if you want the label to change dynamically as the user changes the form data, then it gets a lot uglier and you'll have to resort to [referencing JavaScript media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions) and performing the above on the fly.

Comment: I've updated my question - your answer seems to be the right direction but is not quite there yet.